# c program to read the data between 2 strings

Tags: c++, c

I have a text file called new.txt and it contains the following element

```
vv
vinoop
raju
kiran
regu
ramu
```

I want to read the only the data between "vinoop" & "regu" print it on other file
 so i want output like this

```
raju 
kiran
```

can anyone help me with an example

Comment: let us see what you hav tried

Comment: Read every token, start recording once you meet `vinoop`, and stop recording once you hit `regu`. Then output the recorded string.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for information on how use SO and post appropriate questions.

Comment: @KerrekSB can u demonstrate it with an example

Comment: You won't get very far as a programmer if you ask others to write stuff for you. This is about problem solving, so at least try to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define START_KEYWORD "vinoop"
#define STOP_KEYWORD "regu"

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char line[256];
    int in_range = 0;

    fp=fopen("new.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        int len = strlen(line);
        if(line[len-1]=='\n') line[--len] = '\0';//drop newline
        if(strcmp(START_KEYWORD, line)==0){
            in_range = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(strcmp(STOP_KEYWORD, line)==0){
            in_range = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if(in_range)
            printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `strstr()` to detect the position of `vinoop` and then the first position is the position returned by `strstr()`  + `strlen(vinoop)`

And then use again `strstr()` to detect `regu` in the string (second position) and then you can extract string between theses 2 positions with `strncpy()`

Comment: @StoryTeller Are you sure? The OP certainly doesn't seem to be ... :)

Comment: can u explain using the code

Comment: Yeah, I subconsciously ignored the `c` tag. +1 ^_^

Comment: @user2408085. it's up to you now to write your own code. and If you get problems, go back to SO with a new question to help you